# r proc plot :auc value overlap with Coordinate points

Tags: r, plot, proc, auc

```
fit2<-glm(y~x2+x3+x5+x7+x8+x9+x10,train,family = "binomial")
pre<-predict(fit2,test)
modelroc<-roc(test$y,pre)
plot(modelroc, print.auc=TRUE,location=c(0.2,1),auc.polygon=TRUE, grid=c(0.1, 0.2),
     grid.col=c("green", "red"), max.auc.polygon=TRUE,
     auc.polygon.col="skyblue", print.thres=TRUE)
```

[image]

How can I adjust the location of auc value???
Help me,thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The coordinates of the `auc` in the `plot.roc` function from the library `pROC` can be adjusted using the arguments `print.auc.x` and `print.auc.y`. Example using `Sonar` data set from `mlbench` library:

```
library(mlbench)
library(pROC)
data(Sonar)

fit <- glm(Class ~., Sonar[,c(1:5, 61)], family = "binomial")
preds <- predict(fit, Sonar)
modelroc <- roc(Sonar$Class, preds)
plot(modelroc,
     print.auc = TRUE,
     auc.polygon = TRUE,
     grid=c(0.1, 0.2),
     grid.col = c("green", "red"),
     max.auc.polygon = TRUE,
     auc.polygon.col = "skyblue",
     print.thres = TRUE,
     print.auc.x = 0.3,
     print.auc.y = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me where to find answer or how to find?

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. I found the answer by typing `?plot.roc` or ?pROC::plot.roc.